# How can I ignore specific files from a Git repository?

Tags: git, gitignore

when I use git to control my team project,this file always changed:

`MyProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/user.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate`

How can I ignore this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ignoring files with git, you use the `.gitignore` file in the root of the repository.

Here is a sample that I use with all of my iOS development project at work and personal:

```
# Xcode
.DS_Store
build/
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
*.xcworkspace
!default.xcworkspace
xcuserdata
profile
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
*.hmap
*.ipa
.idea/
# Pods - for those of you who use CocoaPods
Pods
xcuserdata/*
```

Keep note that just adding it to the gitignore will do little of anything.  You also need to remove the file(s) from tracking.

You can do this with: `git rm --cached xcuserdata/*` which will remove it from being tracked, but leave it on the file system.

For more information on gitignore and how it works, I recommend reading the scm documentation on it at http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: first thanks a lot. here i still have a question that when ignored this file, Will  it effect the project on git or not?Also, will it make a trouble to the project or to my colleague?

Comment: Creating that file, you want to commit it so that your colleague has it in his local version as well.  He/She will then be able to do their changes as they feel like without screwing with the repository itself.

I implemented this in our first project about 6 months into it with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

- After adding files to the **.gitignore** file, to ignore those files we have to execute some commands.
- To ignore the files which we mentioned in the **.gitignore** file, we have to execute the following commands.

  `git rm -r --cached .
  git add .
  git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"`
- Please refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository) once.

Answer (score 0):

By adding it or the folder containing the file to .gitignore.

http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore